# how to create hook for LDAPAuth class in liferay 6.1

Tags: ldap, hook, liferay-6

I am trying to hook LDAPAuth class in lliferay 6.1 to override the authenticateByEmailAddress to add some logic from my side. i am not sure how to define this in liferay-hook.xml

```
<hook>
  <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
  <custom-jsp-dir>/jsp_overrides</custom-jsp-dir>
  <service>
    <service-type>com. </service-type>
    <service-impl></service-impl>
  </service>
</hook>
```

what should be provided in the service-type and service-imp. my class name is MyLDAPAuth which extends LDAPauth from liferay

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create a hook to override this class as this class resides in portal-impl.jar which can't be referenced from plugins portlets or hooks (and this is the [reason](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-4157) for it and you can also read this [forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1091443) for more information on why we can't and we should not use portal-impl.jar in plugins).

So the only option which remains is EXT.

Also if you create your custom class in EXT, you will need to specify it in the portal-ext.properties with property (read the comments for this property in portal.properties):

```
auth.pipeline.pre=com.custom.portal.security.auth.MyLDAPAuth
```

I have not tried but I don't think it is possible to create custom class in a plugin portlet or hook and change this property.

Hope this answers your question or atleast gives you an idea for going further.

Thank you